# javafx 8: How to update TreeCell in TreeView on SlectedItemProperty Change

Tags: java, treeview, javafx-2, javafx-8, fxml

I have a tree-view with costume TreeCell. tree cell is customized and it looks like below image.

[image]

On Right Side I selected the One Tree Cell or Tree item. as you can see there is image-view of hand on left side of each cell. By default it is in black color but i want to replace it with white color icon. as in above mock up.

## How can i achieve this????

I want all text and image view icon on selection changed to white color. and last selected tree cell back to normal black color.

My Tree Cell Code is below.

```
private final class AlertTreeCell extends TreeCell<AlertListItem> {

    private Node cell;
    private Rectangle rectSeverity;
    private Label mIncedentname;
    private Label mAlertTitle;
    private Label mSentTime;
    private Label mSender;
    private ImageView ivCategory;
    public AlertTreeCell() {

        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(
                MainController.class
                        .getResource("/fxml/alert_list_item.fxml"));
        try {
            cell = (Node) fxmlLoader.load();
            rectSeverity = (Rectangle) cell.lookup("#rectSeverity");
            mIncedentname = (Label) cell.lookup("#lblIncidentName");
            mAlertTitle = (Label) cell.lookup("#lblAlertTitle");
            mSentTime = (Label) cell.lookup("#lblSentTime");
            mSender = (Label) cell.lookup("#lblSender");
            ivCategory = (ImageView) cell.lookup("#ivCategory");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            mLogger.error(ex.getLocalizedMessage(),ex);
        }           
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(AlertListItem item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            setText(null);
             mAlertTitle.setText(item.getEvent());
             mIncedentname.setText(item.getHeadline());                                   
             mSentTime.setText(MyUtils.getListDateFormattedString(item.getReceivedTime()));
             mSender.setText(item.getSenderName());
             Image image = new Image("/images/ic_cat_" + item.getCategoryIcon().toLowerCase() + "_black.png");
             if(image != null){
                ivCategory.setImage(image);
             }
             if(item.getSeverity() != null){
                 String severityColor = item.getSeverity().toString();
                 String severityColorCode = null;
                 if(severityColor != null) {
                     SeverityColorHelper severityColorHelper = new SeverityColorHelper();
                     severityColorCode = severityColorHelper.getColorBySeverity(AlertInfo.Severity.fromValue(severityColor));
                 }
                 rectSeverity.setFill(Color.web(severityColorCode,1.0) );
             }
             final AlertTreeCell this$=this;
             setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                     if(event.getClickCount()==1){                                
                            Node cell$ = this$.getGraphic();
                            ImageView ivCategory$ = (ImageView) cell.lookup("#ivCategory");
                            Image image = new Image("/images/ic_cat_" + item.getCategoryIcon().toLowerCase() + "_white.png");
                            if(image != null){
                                ivCategory$.setImage(image);
                            }                                                           
                     }

                }
             });
             this$.
             setGraphic(cell);

        }
    }
}
```

problem is that new white icon properly selected and added but how to change back the last selected tree item's image view back to black color icon.  actually I have two color images of same type. one is in black color and same image in white color. on selection i want the image and text changed to white colored and all other tree-items in to black color text and black color icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if the mouse handler is supposed to be changing the icon on selection: if so remove it. Don't use mouse handlers for detecting selection (what if the user navigates through the tree using the keyboard, for example?).

In your constructor, add a listener to the `selectedProperty`, and change the item accordingly:

```
public AlertTreeCell() {

    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(
            MainController.class
                    .getResource("/fxml/alert_list_item.fxml"));
    try {
        cell = (Node) fxmlLoader.load();
        rectSeverity = (Rectangle) cell.lookup("#rectSeverity");
        mIncedentname = (Label) cell.lookup("#lblIncidentName");
        mAlertTitle = (Label) cell.lookup("#lblAlertTitle");
        mSentTime = (Label) cell.lookup("#lblSentTime");
        mSender = (Label) cell.lookup("#lblSender");
        ivCategory = (ImageView) cell.lookup("#ivCategory");

        this.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected) -> {
            String col ;
            if (isNowSelected) {
                col = "_black.png" ;
            } else {
                col = "_white.png" ;
            }
            if (getItem() != null) {
                Image img = new Image("/images/ic_cat_" + item.getCategoryIcon().toLowerCase() + col);
                ivCategory.setImage(img);
            }
        });

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        mLogger.error(ex.getLocalizedMessage(),ex);
    }           
}
```

In the `updateItem(...)` method, just check `isSelected()` and set the image accordingly there, but without the listener.

Comment: i AM CONFUSED WITH YOUR LAST LINE. you mean that without using listener i can use isSelected() method in update item? like if(isSelected()){ do on selection} else {do on not selected}

Comment: I use the Listener Method in constructor and it perfectly solve my problem. Thanks @James_D